# Move file from HDFS one directory to other directory in HDFS using OOZIE?

Tags: shell, hadoop, cloudera, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am trying to copy a file from HDFS one directory to other directory in HDFS, with the help of shell script as a part of oozie Job, but i am not able to copy it through oozie.

Can we copy file from HDFS one directory  to other director in HDFS using oozie.

```
when i am running the oozie job, i am not any getting error.

it is showing status SUCCEEDED but file is not copying to destination directory.
```

oozie Files are below.

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "listing files in the current directory, $PWD"
sudo hadoop fs -cp /user/cloudera/RAVIOOZIE/input/*  /user/cloudera/RAVIOOZIE/output/
ls  # list files
```

my workflow.xml is

```
<workflow-app name="RAMA" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
<start to="shell-381c"/>
<kill name="Kill">
    <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<action name="shell-381c">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <exec>/user/cloudera/test.sh</exec>
        <file>/user/cloudera/test.sh#test.sh</file>
          <capture-output/>
    </shell>
    <ok to="End"/>
    <error to="Kill"/>
</action>
<end name="End"/>
```

and my job.properties

```
oozie.use.system.libpath=True
security_enabled=False
dryrun=True
jobTracker=localhost:8032
nameNode=hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/cloudera/test/
```

please help on this. why file is not copying to my destination director.

please let me know is there any thing i missed.

Comment: your workflow.xml and shell script looks fine. Your may have to carefully look for error - even if it says succeeded. Is your echo statement in shell script getting printed ?

Comment: I am able to see echo statements in "jobhistory/logs" but there its not showing any error .it  showing in log     "    Oozie Launcher, capturing output data:
=======================
hello, cloudera. I wish to list some files of yours
listing files in the current directory, /var/lib/hadoop-yarn/cache/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/cloudera/appcache/application_1470284226059_0022/container_1470284226059_00ror.i.e"

Comment: Your question is labeled *"Move file"* but your post is actually about *copying files*. If you really want to **move** these files, you should try the native Oozie **HDFS Action** https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.4_Fs_HDFS_action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @Samson:

If you want to do hadoop actions with oozie, you should use a [hdfs action](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a3.2.4_Fs_HDFS_action) rather than a shell action for that.

---

I am not sure why you don't get an error, but here is some speculation on what might happen:

You give oozie the task of starting a shell action, it succesfully starts the shell action and reports a success. Then the shell action fails, but that's not oozies problem.